How to create an aws event rule that listens on a server health check?
I want to listen on when my server is up to trigger an application. For the moment I'm simply testing to see if I can log an output as soon as my server is up.
This is my task definition health check
{

      "name": "nginx-example",
      "healthCheck": {
        "command": [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -f http://localhost:80/ || exit 1"
        ],
        "interval": 30,
        "timeout": 5,
        "retries": 3,
        "startPeriod": 10
      }
}


This is my event rule:
{
  "Name": "rule-nginx-ok",
  "EventPattern":  "{\"source\": [\"aws.ecs\"], \"detail-type\": [\"ECS Task State Change\"], \"detail\": {\"lastStatus\": [\"RUNNING\"], \"healthStatus\": [\"HEALTHY\"], \"containers\": {\"name\": [\"nginx-example\"]}}}",
  "State": "ENABLED",
  "Description": "Rule to capture ECS nginx health check OK events"
}

Which triggers a target that outputs to my logs.
I have all permissions setup. I can trigger an event manually and this will show in my lambda log.
{
    "time": 1697929865000,
    "detail": {
        "lastStatus": "RUNNING",
        "healthStatus": "HEALTHY",
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "nginx-example"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Though the nginx server, when its up, despite health check ok, is not triggering this rule.
I'm just wondering if I have missed something with my event rule?

most likely your rule doesn't match.

@erik358 thanks. Do you know what the rule would be? I tried changing it to the bare minimum, ie the event pattern  just an empty json {} Still my nginx health status doesn't seem to emit anything as a cloudwatch event.

I'm not sure {} is going to match anything.  I would start with "{\"source\": [\"aws.ecs\"]}" and see what you get.

I couldn't get this rule to work. I ended up using a subscription instead:
aws logs put-subscription-filter \
 --log-group-name $project_repo \
  --filter-name "HealthCheckSuccessFilter" \
  --filter-pattern "$NGINX_READY_MESSAGE" \
  --destination-arn $FunctionArn

